# How can I use git to deploy JUST one feature at a time after QA and Business Acceptance?

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, agile, feature-branch

## What we need:

My team is maintaining and adding features to a product that's already in production. We are trying to figure out how to improve our deployment strategy so that we can begin deploying one feature at-a-time instead of large chunks of features. Ideally, when a feature passes QA and Business Acceptance, we would like to deploy JUST that feature to production (at any time).

## What we are doing now: (that doesn't work)

We are already following the concept of "Branch per Feature". Right now, we are creating new feature branches off of our development branch. When we are finished with a feature, we create a pull-request back to the dev branch. That pull request looks GREAT... it only has the changes that are relevant to the feature. After code-review, the branch is merged into dev master (and deployed to dev) and QA takes a look. Once QA approves the feature, we merge the original feature branch into the staging branch (and deploy to staging). Once the business accepts the new feature, the original feature branch is merged into production. Our problem is that the original feature branch seems to snowball by the time it gets to production with many changes that don't seem relevant to the feature branch. In the end, we have deployed to production many things that were not QAed or accepted by the business.

Answer (score 0):

[Branch by abstraction](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html) with [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) rather than have long running [feature branches](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do branch per feature properly. Somehow the entire linux kernel seems to do well with this strategy. It applies at the micro level as well.

[Branch per Feature](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/)